# boost asio cancellation signal

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, asio

code snippet:

```cpp
template<typename CompletionToken>
boost::awaitable<int> async_op(CompletionToken) {...}

boost::asio::cancellation_signal cancel_signal;
...
auto value = co_await async_op(boost::asio::bind_cancellation_slot(
    cancel_token.slot(),
    boost::asio::use_awaitable));
...

// use signal
cancel_signal.emit(boost::asio::cancellation_type::total);
```

I have 2 questions

1. is that correct/most basic pattern of how to cancel a coroutine. those that support of course.
2. Are there other ways to perform the same. In particular, what if one does not have access to the exact signal.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the most basic pattern is to use the (experimental) awaitable operators, like so:

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

namespace io = boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

io::awaitable<void> Cancelled(io::steady_timer& cancelTimer)
{
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    co_await cancelTimer.async_wait(io::redirect_error(io::use_awaitable, ec));
}

io::awaitable<void> AsyncOp(io::io_context& context)
{
    io::steady_timer timer{ context, 100ms };
    co_await timer.async_wait(io::use_awaitable);
}

io::awaitable<void> Run(io::io_context& context, io::steady_timer& cancelTimer)
{
    const auto result { co_await(AsyncOp(context) || Cancelled(cancelTimer)) };
    if (result.index() == 0)
        std::cout << "AsyncOp completed" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "AsyncOp cancelled" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        io::io_context context;
        io::steady_timer cancelTimer{ context, 
              std::chrono::steady_clock::duration::max() };

        io::co_spawn(context, Run(context, cancelTimer), io::detached);

        std::future<void> contextRun{ std::async([&context] { context.run(); }) };

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
        cancelTimer.cancel();

        contextRun.get();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I highly recommend watching [Talk Async](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icgnqFM-aY4).